# How is the truststore transferred dynamically from the bridge to the float?

Tags: corda

the Corda docs mention that the truststore is dynamically transferred from the Bridge to the Float and stored only in memory. https://www.corda.net/blog/corda-firewall-components-pki-deployment/

> truststore.jks is dynamically transferred to the float by the bridge and is stored only in memory.

But when looking at the corda-kubernetes-deployment repo, a directory for the trustStoreFile and sslKeystore is given in the float.conf file. https://github.com/corda/corda-kubernetes-deployment/blob/master/helm/files/conf/float-4.5.conf

```
     sslKeystore: "certificates/float.jks"
     trustStoreFile: "certificates/trust.jks"
```

Is a manual step needed to copy the truststore from the Bridge to Float?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing the intent of the question, you're going to get the truststore files from the maintainer of the network that you're joining.

If you are setting this up yourself be aware that you'll need to generate the files yourself to then copy them into the conf folder.

This tutorial may be useful for you as well:

"Download network root truststore to ./helm/files/network with the name networkRootTrustStore.jks (must match spelling exactly)
Configure matching truststorePassword to the truststore."

From here: https://github.com/corda/corda-kubernetes-deployment/blob/master/docs/CHECKLIST.md#network-setup

Good luck!